# square roots algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to follow along with this: https://dandavison.github.io/fibonacci-eigenbasis.html

And I'm getting stuck on what's presumably very basic algebra. The step that's giving me trouble is going from:
$$
\frac{-1}{2\sqrt5}
\begin{bmatrix}
-5-\sqrt5 & 0 \\
0 & 5-\sqrt5 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
to:
$$
\frac{1}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1+\sqrt5 & 0 \\
0 & 1-\sqrt5 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

the closest i can get is:
$$
\frac{1}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
5(1+\sqrt5) & 0 \\
0 & 5(1-\sqrt5) \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and I don't understand how the extra factor of 5 comes out. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author distributed the $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ into each component of the matrix. This gives us
$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(-5-\sqrt{5}) = \frac{5}{\sqrt{5}}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt5} = \sqrt5+1$$
and
$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(5-\sqrt{5}) = -\frac{5}{\sqrt{5}}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt5} = -\sqrt5+1$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer florence. I see now I was trying to treat it like balancing an equation rather than distributing terms inside the matrix (i.e. I was trying to multiply by $\sqrt5$ rather than divide). 

It also wasn't intuitively obvious to me that $\frac{5}{\sqrt5}$ would equal $\sqrt5$. Seems I am rustier than I first though. Thanks again!